# How can I store the favorite links of a user in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, user-profile

I have a task that to allow a user to add his favorite links of **any website** and then they are stored in SharePoint. Then they will be shown in a panel called "My Bookmarks".

I have a solution that creates a list for all users with a "CreatedBy" field but I think it is slow to load. Do you have any solution, a custom solution or a OOTB solution?

Comment: aka My Links Web Part from MySite ? http://www.mylifeinaminute.com/2011/04/04/sharepoint-2010-my-links-web-part-outside-the-my-site-host/

Comment: hi @user1379816, what solution did you implement? any update?

Comment: Too late for replying now, but I uses kist in My Sites

Answer (score 0):

you could use the 'links' list that is ootb. if you are wanting something that is cross sites , and collections you will need to create a custom webpart. with that you will need to either hit a sql table or sp list.... for example -> id, userid, sitename, url. so you'll have to get the currently logged in user. so something like -> select * from tableName where @currentUser = userid......

Comment: Many user's favorite links are stored in a list can make the site bad performance ?

Comment: about 25.000 members, favorites is not limited